# How to get a second stockpile?

Tags: craft-the-world

It is very painful for the dwarves to have to go back to the stockpile, not to mention that their AI is not that great.

How can I get additional stockpiles or move my stockpile underground ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft warehouses, but only in the late game: http://crafttheworld.gamepedia.com/Warehouse.
As you can see in the new tech tree it's tier 10 engineering: http://crafttheworld.gamepedia.com/Tech_Tree#Technology_Tree.

You cannot move your initial stockpile, and digging underneath it is forbidden.